# Why a PubSubEvent raised in a module is not being caught in the Shell?

Tags: prism, prism-5

I have a problem that is an exact opposite of this: [Prism, Event published in shell not caught in module!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109518/prism-event-published-in-shell-not-caught-in-module)

The event is raised in one of my modules and is published like this:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<ButtonEvent>().Publish("hello");
```

The subscription looks like this:

```
this._eventAggregator.GetEvent<ButtonEvent2>().Subscribe(method1, true);
```

When the event is raised, the other program modules' subscriptions work fine, but the shell does not recieve messages.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Why does your subscription take the `ButtonEvent2` while a `ButtonEvent` is published? Can you ensure that the `IEventAggregator` instance is the same in both the module and the shell?

Comment: Sorry the 2 was a mistake i left in from debugging, and i believe if i understand how unity containers work they are the same but I dont quite know how to check

Comment: I found out the answer thanks to your help dymanoid.
The problem was using the same instance in both, i solved it by when calling the shell initialization in the boot stapper, passing in an event aggregator resolved from a unity container thanks for the help.